# Inject/embed/$sanitize HTML into AngularJS from JSON data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, soundcloud

I am faced with an issue that I cannot find a solution for.

So I am trying to create an application that will display tracks taken from soundcloud and display them on my page using the soundcloud embeded player. I will be using DjangoREST to create a JSON list of all the tracks I want displayed. The JSON will have an entry to store the embeded HTML and will be packaged up and sent to the AngularJS front end.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to actually display the embeded HTML even after using `ng-bind-html`.

I created a small demo to demonstrate the issue I am facing.

**app.js**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("tracklist", []);

    app.controller("TrackListController", function () {
        this.tracks = soundcloudtracks;
    });

    // Very basic JSON track coming in from DjangoREST
    var soundcloudtracks = [
        {
            title: 'Track1',
            artist: 'Artist1',
            html: '<iframe width="100%" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F150879755&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;client_id=e72237107739281ffceb867534efd87c"></iframe>',
        },
        {
            title: 'Test2',
            artist: 'Artist2',
            html: '<iframe width="100%" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F150879755&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;client_id=e72237107739281ffceb867534efd87c"></iframe>',
        },
    ]
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tracklist">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <div ng-controller="TrackListController as tracklistcont">
                <div ng-repeat="track in tracklistcont.tracks">
                    <h1>{{ track.title }} - {{ track.artist }} </h1>
                    <div ng-bind-html="track.html"></div>            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

From my understanding I need to [`$sanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) the incoming HTML but I don't know how to properly sanitize each element within an ng-repeat. Could anyone help me out? I am completely lost at this point.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so I believe I was able to resolve the issue. I just created a method to sanitize my html.

**app.js**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("tracklist", ['ngSanitize']);

    app.controller("TrackListController", ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
        this.tracks = soundcloudtracks;
        $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function(html) {
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
        };
    }]);

    // Very basic JSON track coming in from DjangoREST
    var soundcloudtracks = [
        {
            title: 'Track1',
            artist: 'Artist1',
            html: '<iframe width="100%" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F150879755&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;client_id=e72237107739281ffceb867534efd87c"></iframe>',
            url: 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood',
        },
        {
            title: 'Test2',
            artist: 'Artist2',
            html: '<iframe width="100%" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?visual=true&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F150879755&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;client_id=e72237107739281ffceb867534efd87c"></iframe>',
            url: 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood',
        },
    ]
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="tracklist">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <div ng-controller="TrackListController as tracklistcont">
                <div ng-repeat="track in tracklistcont.tracks">
                    <h1>{{ track.title }} - {{ track.artist }} </h1>
                    <div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet(track.html)"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now everything is working as expected!